# How to search (query) for particular element value insight XML? Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

How to search for particular xml attribute (descriptor) value across whole XML and return ID + Protection values?
I have this code:

```
$Xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" format="low_level">

    <ToolDgnPart Protection="Restricted" id="169487" creation_date="2022-06-03T15:10:14Z"/>
    <Rel elemId="id1414" id="42432"/>
    <Form Protection="Restricted" id="2347890" creation_date="2022-06-03T15:10:14Z"/>
    <View Protection="Restricted" id="2342345" creation_date="2022-06-03T15:10:14Z"/>
    
</TCXML>
'@

$xml.TCXML.ToolDgnPart | Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted' | ForEach-Object {


[pscustomobject]@{
        ID = $_.id
        Protection = $_.Protection
    }
}
```

Powers shell is returning right value but only for one Attribute (ToolDgnPart) as designed:

```
ID     Protection
--     ----------
169487 Restricted
```

The goal is to make this proces generic to return all ID's values of all "Restricted" objects (ToolDgnPart, Rel, Form, View) **without** declaring each one as single line, ie:

```
$xml.TCXML.ToolDgnPart | Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted'
$xml.TCXML.Rel | Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted'
$xml.TCXML.Form | Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted'
$xml.TCXML.View | Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted'
```

THX in advance
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [`XmlNode.SelectNodes` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlnode.selectnodes)  to iterate through the child nodes:

```
$xml.TCXML.SelectNodes('*') |Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted'
```

```
Protection id      creation_date
---------- --      -------------
Restricted 169487  2022-06-03T15:10:14Z
Restricted 2347890 2022-06-03T15:10:14Z
Restricted 2342345 2022-06-03T15:10:14Z
```

Comment: Hi. Great!. I have one trouble more:) When I move content of XML definition to file The script is not working any more... any clue? To read content I am using [xml]$xml = Get-Content -path C:\temp\input2.xml

Comment: You need to be more clear on"*The script is not working any more..*". What happens instead? Any errors? You might consider to open an new question for this. Long shot: encoding issue: make sure your file is saved as ascii or utf8 without bom.

Comment: Yes, You right: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73166227/powershell-how-to-selecthodes-from-get-content-variable