# Powershell - How to SelectNodes from Get-Content variable

Tags: xml, powershell

I have this powershell code:

```
$Xml = [xml]@'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TCXML xmlns="http://www.tcxml.org/Schemas/TCXMLSchema" format="low_level">
    <ToolDgnPart Protection="Restricted" id="169487" creation_date="2022-06-03T15:10:14Z"/>
    <Rel elemId="id1414" id="42432"/>
    <Form Protection="Restricted" id="2347890" creation_date="2022-06-03T15:10:14Z"/>
    <View Protection="Restricted" id="2342345" creation_date="2022-06-03T15:10:14Z"/>
</TCXML>
'@
$xml.TCXML.SelectNodes('*') |Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted' | ForEach-Object {
[pscustomobject]@{
        ID = $_.id
        Protection = $_.Protection
    }
}
```

Result:

```
ID      Protection
--      ----------
169487  Restricted
2347890 Restricted
2342345 Restricted
```

It works as designed only when I have XML content in powershell ISE.

The whole problems begins when I want to read file and parse content through script.
Assume that content is saved to input2.xml file:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content -path 'C:\temp\input2.xml'
$xml.TCXML.SelectNodes('*') |Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted' | ForEach-Object {

[pscustomobject]@{
        ID = $_.id
        Protection = $_.Protection
    }
}
```

Result:

```
ID ACL_ProtectIntern
-- -----------------
```

Any clues why??
Mike

Comment: The output would suggest you ran some other code than what you're actually showing here - where would `ACL_ProtectIntern` come from otherwise?

Comment: `Where-Object Protection -eq 'Restricted'` --> `Where-Object {$_.Protection -eq 'Restricted'}`